# Yii2 index view own data

Tags: php, yii2

It is working fine as long as there is at least one record, but throws error, which seems to be obvious, but am not able to find a way to fix it.

The code I am using is like:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CommandsSearch();
        $cond = "user_id= " . Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams,$cond);
        $dataProvider->query->andWhere('user_id =' . Yii::$app->user->identity->id);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

I want to show the gridview page with option to add records.

update:

```
return [
         'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::classname(),
            'only'  => ['index','view','create','update','delete'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin','manager','user'],                        
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                            if (Yii::$app->user->can('admin') || $this->isUserAuthor()) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
            throw new \Exception('You are not allowed to access this page');
                    }                
        ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

and the isUserAuthor method like:

```
protected function isUserAuthor()
    {   
       // $author= $this->findModel($_GET["id"]); 
        $author= Commands::findOne(['user_id'=>\Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
       // var_dump($author->user_id);exit;
        return $author;
    }
```

Comment: not clear from your question what you are asking, when and what error do you get ?

Comment: Hi Omer, not exactly an error, it is an exception - You are not allowed to access this page. as I have added the rule I am adding in the question.

Comment: what i understood so far is that you have an access rule defined where you use `matchCallback` and `denyCallback` to check the access, and you are getting denied for the `index` action although it is listed in the rules, but i am still not able to relate it to your first line **it is working fine as long as there is at least one record, but throws error,**

Comment: HI Omer - that's correct if I have at least one matching record, I don't get any error, when I tried to acess the index page as new user having no record, then I am getting the error - you are not allowed to access this page.

Comment: because you checked it in `isUserAuthor()` whereas it returns null on no record for new user.

Comment: then you should add the respctive commands for the newly created user as soon as you create the user, @InsaneSkull has pointed it correctly, that you dont have any commands in the `Commands` models and it returns null so it wont allow you .

Comment: You need to set up permission for this case you can display and filter record as per loggedin user but for access purpose permission is required.